# Algorithm to create a x-ray image from a volume

Tags: algorithm, visualization, computer-vision, data-visualization

What is the algorithm to create a x-ray image using ray-tracing from a 3-d volume?

Comment: Any reason for negative score?

Comment: probably because the questions is too general.  Are you looking for a name of an algorithm or a full implementation.  If it is a full implementation then you can expect some resistance.  If it is a name then you should say that in the title and/or body.

Comment: I was asked to implement x-ray algorithm as part of my course. But, I couldn't find the algorithm anywhere. The description given is not precise. If you could give the name and also the algorithm, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate integral(density*dl), where l is ray length, as the ray passes through the volume.  The algorithm comes down to, what integration method, how do you interpolate the densities, do you interpolate between rays and if so how, and what is the optimal set of rays to use if you're using interpolation.  And of course, how do you represent the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that what is desired is a radiograph as opposed to some kind of hidden surface visualization.

**Unnecessarily heavy, but extremely flexible and realistic approach:** simulate the machine and subject volume in [geant](http://www.geant4.org/geant4/). Or, if you prefer coding in Fortran, [geant 3](http://wwwasdoc.web.cern.ch/wwwasdoc/geant_html3/geantall.html) is also more than equal to the task.